# how to draw curved line in a qgsmapcanvas

Tags: qgis, line, api, c++, curved

i am working on a project with qt4.8.6, api c++ of qgis 2.8.2
we need to draw curved line in a vectorlayer by given 2 points and an offset by exemple

is it possible to do that with the c++ api of qgis ?